# In JMETER, how to extract select name and option value both based on specific text

Tags: jquery, html, regex, xpath, jmeter

I am stuck with a problem and need your help in resolving this.

The webpage I am testing has lots of fields and among those are some repeating fields. 
One of those fields is a select list having varying number of options. Sometimes it has only 1 option ("Default") and at times it has 2 options ("Default" and "Custom"). For further processing this request, I am interested in only those select lists which have the option value of "Custom" selected. So, if the select list has "Default" selected then I want to ignore it. But I want to extract only those fields where the option "Custom" is selected. In that case, I want to extract the select list name AND the value of the option, both.

The select lists in the page look like this:

```
<select id="delOpt1" name="delOpt1" class="dd">
<option select="selected" value="1406">Default</option>
</select>

<select id="delOpt2" name="delOpt2" class="dd">
<option value="13987">Default</option>
<option selected="selected" value="18902">Custom</option>
</select>

<select id="delOpt3" name="delOpt3" class="dd">
<option value="2101">Default</option>
<option selected="selected" value="21921">Custom</option>
</select>

<select id="delOpt4" name="delOpt4" class="dd">
<option select="selected" value="3232">Default</option>
</select>
```

So in this case I want only the following two to be extracted:

- delOpt2=218092
- delOpt3=21921

So far, I am able to extract only the select name OR option value but not both. I've tried XPath Extractor, CSS/JQuery Extractor and Regular Expression Extractor. But they can extract only 1 value at a time. Even if I use 2 different extractors and store values in 2 variables, there is no way for me to relate the select name with option value.

I get all the select lists like:

```
CSS/JQuery Extractor
Reference: delOptSelectName
CSS/JQuery expression: select[class=dd]
Attribute: name
Match No.: 1
Default Value: NOTFOUND
```

This gives me

```
Match[1]=delOpt1
Match[2]=delOpt2
Match[3]=delOpt3
Match[4]=delOpt4
```

I can get all option values like:

```
CSS/JQuery Extractor
Reference: optionValues
CSS/JQuery expression: select[class=dd] option
Attribute: value
Match No.: 1
Default Value: NOTFOUND
```

This gives me

```
Match count: 6
Match[1]=1406
Match[2]=13987
Match[3]=18902
Match[4]=2101
Match[5]=21921
Match[6]=3232
```

Alternately I get only those options which are selected

```
CSS/JQuery Extractor
Reference: optionValues
CSS/JQuery expression: select[class=dd] option[selected=selected]
Attribute: value
Match No.: 1
Default Value: NOTFOUND
```

This gives me

```
Match count: 4
Match[1]=1406
Match[2]=18902
Match[3]=21921
Match[4]=3232
```

So now I have 4 select lists and 4 options but how do I compare which option values belong to those which have option as "Custom" and for that how do I get the select name?

Any pointers to resolve this will be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

-Hemal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go for the following XPath expression:

```
//select/option[text()='Custom']/../@name | //select/option[text()='Custom']/@value
```

It will return something like

```
option_1=delOpt2
option_2=18902
option_3=delOpt3
option_4=21921
```

So odd numbers would be select names and even numbers - option values.

For more information on XPath language see [XPath specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/), [XPath Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/) and [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) guide.